# ListBoxの背景にDrap&Dropする際にDrop先Indexを計算するには？

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

`ListBox`上の`ListBoxItem`、または`ListBox`上の`ListBox.Background`が見えている領域に対してDrag&Dropを行い、要素の並べ替え/挿入を行おうとしています。

この時、`ListBox`の背景要素にDropした際、Dropした位置によって適切な挿入先のIndexを計算する方法が分からず、詰まってしまっています。

**- 出来たこと**
`ListBox`上の`ListBoxItem`に対するDropは、`DragEventArgs.OriginalSource`を使って現在Dropしようとしている先の`FrameworkElement`を特定→`ListBox.ItemsSource`から`DataContext`の内容で探す……などの方法でDrop先Indexを計算する事ができました。

**- 出来なくて困っていること(知りたいこと)**
`ListBox`上のDrop位置において、以下の図のような領域⇔Index値となる計算をしたいのですが、以下の3点を計算・区別する方法が分かりませんでした。

1. `ListBoxItem`間のMarginの位置へのDrop時のIndex計算
2. `WrapPanel`での折り返し位置(図上のIndex 4の位置)へのDrop時のIndex計算
3. 1,2に含まれない末尾全般領域(図上のIndex 6の位置)へのDrop時のIndex計算

[image: WrapPanel上のDrop位置と期待するIndex値]

実現方法が分かる方、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

泥臭い解法ですが…`ListBoxItem`の領域を左上から順に取得し、マウス座標の手前にあるかどうかを判定する方法で実装できます。

下記のサンプルコードでは、`GetNextItem`メソッドでマウス座標直後にある`ListBoxItem`を取得し、リスト内のインデックスは`MoveItem`メソッド内の`IList.IndexOf`で取得しています。

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml の相互作用ロジック
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ListBoxItem DropTarget;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
            LstSample.MouseMove += LstSample_MouseMove;
            LstSample.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += LstSample_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;
            LstSample.Drop += LstSample_Drop;
        }

        private void LstSample_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed || DropTarget == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop((ListBox)sender, DropTarget, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

        private void LstSample_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DropTarget = null;
        }

        private void LstSample_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DropTarget == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var listBox = (ListBox)sender;
            var list = (IList)listBox.ItemsSource;
            MoveItem(list, DropTarget, GetNextItem(listBox, e.GetPosition(listBox)));
            listBox.ItemsSource = null;
            listBox.ItemsSource = list;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dropした位置の直後にあるListBoxItemを取得する。該当がなければnullを返す
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="listBox"></param>
        /// <param name="drop"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static ListBoxItem GetNextItem(ListBox listBox, Point drop)
        {
            return listBox.ItemsSource.OfType<ListBoxItem>().FirstOrDefault(q =>
            {
                //ListBoxItemの左上座標
                var p = q.TranslatePoint(new Point(), listBox);
                //ドロップした位置が、現在のListBoxItem上端より上
                if (drop.Y < p.Y - q.Margin.Top) return true;
                //ListBoxItem中央下部座標
                p.Offset(q.Width / 2d, q.Height);
                //ドロップした位置が、現在のListBoxItem下端より下
                if (p.Y < drop.Y) return false;
                //ドロップした位置が、現在のListBoxItem行内
                return (drop.X < p.X);
            });
        }

        private static void MoveItem(IList list, ListBoxItem target, ListBoxItem next)
        {
            var delIndex = list.IndexOf(target);
            if (next == null)
            {
                list.Add(target);
            }
            else
            {
                var index = list.IndexOf(next);
                delIndex += (index < delIndex) ? 1 : 0;
                list.Insert(index, target);
            }
            list.RemoveAt(delIndex);
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var list = new List<ListBoxItem>
            {
                GetItem("1"),
                GetItem("2"),
                GetItem("3"),
                GetItem("4"),
                GetItem("5"),
            };
            LstSample.ItemsSource = list;
            LstSample.Items.IsLiveSorting = true;
        }

        private ListBoxItem GetItem(string content)
        {
            var item = new ListBoxItem
            {
                Content = content,
                Width = 150,
                Height = 150,
                Margin = new Thickness(15),
                HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue),
            };
            item.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                DropTarget = item;
            };
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="LstSample" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" AllowDrop="True">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

Drop可能な領域にDrop用の`ListBoxItem`を敷き詰めたダミーの`ListBox`を新たに設けてはどうでしょうか。これで元の`ListBoxItem`のMargin領域、折り返し領域、要素未配置領域は考慮せずに済むかと思います。図表の黒枠の通りの`ListBox`を新たに作成するようなイメージです。

処理の流れのみで申し訳ないですが、
仮に元の並べ替え・挿入対象の`ListBox`を「ItemsPanel」、新たな`ListBox`を「DropItemsPanel」として、「ItemsPanel」の`ListBoxItem`Drag開始で「DropItemsPanel」を有効化し、「DropItemsPanel」の`ListBoxItem`へDropします。そのIndex値を取得し、「ItemsPanel」の並べ替え・挿入処理を行い、「DropItemsPanel」を再び非表示、という実装です。

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="400" Width="600">
<Grid>        
    <ListBox Name="ItemsPanel" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBoxItem Background="Aquamarine" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10" Content="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <ListBoxItem Background="Aquamarine" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10" Content="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <ListBoxItem Background="Aquamarine" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10" Content="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <ListBoxItem Background="Aquamarine" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10" Content="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <ListBoxItem Background="Aquamarine" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10" Content="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <ListBoxItem Background="Aquamarine" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10" Content="6" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox Name="DropItemsPanel" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" AllowDrop="True" Opacity="0.5" Margin="-60,0,-60,0">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="1" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="2" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="3" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="4" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="5" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="6" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="7" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="8" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="8" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="8" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="8" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="8" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="8" />
        <ListBoxItem Width="120" Height="120" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" Content="8" />
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```